# Thread safe usage of CallContext.LogicalSetData

Tags: c#, multithreading, executioncontext

I am using CallContext.LogicalGetData in order to share information across asynchronous code.

I want to perform this kind of call in a 'thread-safe' fashion:

```
var val = CallContext.LogicalGetData(key);
if(val==null)
{
   CallContext.LogicalSetData(key, initialValue);
}
return val;
```

Any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();

public static object GetData(string key, object initialValue)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
       object val = CallContext.LogicalGetData(key);
       if (val == null)
           CallContext.LogicalSetData(key, initialValue);
       return val;
    }
}
```

Note: The class or method do not have to be static. Just make sure that all the threads use the same lock when accesing the critical section.

Comment: You're so right, I don't need a lock per context, one lock is enough =) Thank you !

Comment: For performance reasons, I think it would even be better to put the lock after the null check.

Comment: @David I wouldn't do that. Reading the variable should be thread-safe too.

Comment: This locks every time this method is executed. You only want to lock if you absolutely have to, right? Shouldn't this be like this: 
            if (CallContext.LogicalGetData(key) == null)
            {
                lock (_Lock)
                {
                    if (CallContext.LogicalGetData(key) == null)
                        CallContext.LogicalSetData(key, o);
                }
            }